# how to return true or false when i code window.confirm myself

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
 (function (proxied) {
    window.confirm = function (msg) {
        noty({
            text: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle">'+msg+'</i>',
            theme: 'relax',
            dismissQueue: true,
            layout: 'center',
            buttons: [
                {
                    addClass: 'btn btn-success btn-circle', text: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>', onClick: function ($noty) {
                        $noty.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                {
                    addClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-circle', text: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>', onClick: function ($noty) {
                        $noty.close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        //return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(window.confirm);
```

It can not correct return true or false, I guess it may be  the buttons closures ?Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is `noty({})`? Is noty a defined function?

Comment: Are you sure that the function is called?

Comment: noty - a jQuery Notification Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Only the native dialog functions can pause JavaScript execution until some action is taken which means you won't be able to return anything. You will have to use callbacks:

```
(function (proxied) {
    window.confirm = function (msg, callback) {
        noty({
            text: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle">'+msg+'</i>',
            theme: 'relax',
            dismissQueue: true,
            layout: 'center',
            buttons: [
                {
                    addClass: 'btn btn-success btn-circle', text: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>', onClick: function ($noty) {
                        $noty.close();
                        callback(true);
                    }
                },
                {
                    addClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-circle', text: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>', onClick: function ($noty) {
                        $noty.close();
                        callback(false);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        //return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(window.confirm);
```

To use your function you will then have to do this:

```
window.confirm("Do you want ice cream?", function(result){
    if(result){
        // The user wants ice cream
    }
});
```